# python to get substring of an excel cell with a condition

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to concatenate several csv files and create a 'DATE_TIME' column based on the specific column 'NAME'. I apply an IF condition for extract the substring of DATE_TIME from NAME based on the appearance of a string 'RE'.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

path_dataset = r'C:\Users\test'

def get_file(path_dataset):
    files = os.listdir(path_dataset) #check file list
    files.sort() #sort file
    file_list = []
    for file in files:
        path = path_dataset + "\\" + file
        if (file.startswith("test")) and (file.endswith(".csv")):
        file_list.append(path)
    return (file_list)

read_columns = ['NAME']

read_files = get_file(path_dataset)

all_df = []

for file in read_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols = read_columns)

    if (str(df['NAME'].astype(str).str[23:25]) == 'RE-'):
        df['DATE_TIME'] = df['NAME'].astype(str).str[26:40]
    else:
        df['DATE_TIME'] = df['NAME'].astype(str).str[22:37]
    
all_df.append(df)

Concat_table = pd.concat(all_df, axis=0)
Concat_table = Concat_table.sort_values(['DATE_TIME'])

Concat_table.head()
Concat_table.to_csv(os.path.join(path_dataset, 'Concate_all.csv'), index=False)
```

My question is at the IF-ELSE statement. They return the same position of the substring, so that I  get result below. This is not what I want, with the name 'RE' I still want to extract the date and time. What did I make a mistake for the code? Thank you.

[image]

Added my dataframe:

```
dic1 = {"NAME": ['1234567890-ABCDEFGHIJ-RE-20210802-194706', 
'1234567890-ABCDEFGHIJ-20210801-200321']}
dic2 = {"NAME": ['1234567890-ABCDEFGHIJ-RE-20210731-050457', 
'1234567890-ABCDEFGHIJ-20210801-122356']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dic1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dic2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of IF statement. Split on - and concat the 2 last elements

### EDIT

```py
f = lambda x: (x["NAME"].split("-"))[-2] + "-" + (x["NAME"].split("-"))[-1].replace('.xlsx', '')
for file in read_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols = read_columns)

    df['DATE_TIME'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you. But it shows an error message: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Can you paste a sample of the data frame (in code, not screenshot)  So that I can easily reproduce and iterate ?

Comment: Hi Benoit, I added my dataframe under my question. You can use these two to concatenate and added a column as my original attempt.

Comment: I just edited my answer, it works on my side

Comment: It works for me too! Thank you so much Benoit. I have one further question. My real dataset has ".xlsx" at the end of the time, for example: "1234567890-ABCDEFGHIJ-20210801-122356.xlsx". How can I remove ".xlsx" by split()?

Answer (score 0):

I will try something different, maybe using split function :

```
txt = "01234568790 ABCDEDEFG-RE-20110101"
x = txt.split("RE-", 1)[1]
```

I'm searching for "RE-" pattern, and then i split the string into 2 elements`, 1)` keeping the second one. `[1]`

In your case:

```
fullstring = "01234568790 ABCDEDEFG-RE-20110101"
substring = "RE-"

if substring in fullstring:
    x = txt.split("RE-", 1)[1]
else:
    do something else
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Python. How to apply your approach to my code for dataframe?